# Transparent Css problems

Tags: html, css

```
 body{
   color:red;
   background-image: url("image.jpg");
   background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
 }
```

This my css code for semi-transparent. It's not working. It completely overwrite my image. So, I tried to put  `background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);` into other section like `h2` or `p`. It works fine.

Does anyone can tell me what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `background-color: rgba(...)`?

Comment: Or are you trying to make the actual background image transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Your shorthand `background:` property overwrites the previous longhand `background-image` property.

Do this instead:

```
body {
    color: red;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85) url("image.jpg");
}
```

Alternatively, use two long-hand properties:

```
body {
    color: red;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Both method does not working. I tried both method. They just show the color just for 1 second then the image overwrite them.

Comment: @user3822798 isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your short-hand property of background overrides the background, so you need to do like this:

```
body{
 color:red;
 background: url("image.jpg") no-repeat;//now it works which doesn't support rgba
 background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the transparent image using `pseudo` element. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lekihucu/1/edit)**.

```
div{
  color: red;
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
}
div:after
{
 content: "";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 opacity: 0.5;
 -moz-opacity: 0.5;
 background: url("http://lorempixel.com/700/700/") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3822798 You are not understanding background property correctly.

When you use,

```
 body{
   color:red;
   background-image: url("image.jpg");
   background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
 }
```

`background` property which is at las overrides `background-image`, thus you see only color.

But as mentioned by @Dai if you use,

```
body {
    color: red;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

You can get both image & color at same time, but since your image is in jpeg format, it is opaque & you can not see color behind it.

to see it use a small background image & use this code,

```
body {
    color: red;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    background-image: url("image-small.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

You can see transparent white color & your small image in middle.

***Now my question is, why the hell do all this things? can't you simply use a transparent PNG?***

Make a transperant PNG Image & use following code:

```
body {
    color: red;
    background:url("image.png");
}
```